# How to apply OBTRUSIVE validation to dynamic content in ASP.NET MVC / jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, dynamic, jquery-validate

There are lots of references on how to apply "unobtrusive" validation to dynamic content in MVC 3. For instance, if I load a form or refresh it via jQuery ajax, I may want to (re)apply validation to it using "$.validator.unobtrusive.parse...".
I am using OBTRUSIVE validation, however, and I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Is there a way to do this? :)

Please keep in mind, the form element(s) may never have existed on the form prior to my AJAX call.

IE:

1. Page is loaded
2. User does something to trigger AJAX call, a partial view is loaded via jQuery.ajax that contains a form
3. Attach client-side validation to the new form

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found "A WAY" to do this. It may not be the best way so I'd like to hear any other solutions. If a better one is provided I'll pick that as the solution.

Basically what I've found is I can repopulate the

```
window.mvcClientValidationMetadata
```

...array and then call:

```
Sys.Mvc.FormContext._Application_Load()
```

Which will empty the array and parse the validation JSON.